# Passing value pairs inside procedure with each iteration

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, cursor

I am creating a procedure, where one of the input parameters is:
1 - string of numbers separated by semicolon

```
for example: lv_string VARCHAR2(100) := '10; 20; 30';
```

then I have a cursor that fetches numbers

```
for example: lv_cur that stores values 1, 2, 3
```

And I have a procedure where I´m having problem finding out the solution how to pass:

```
1. iteration 
   procedure process_input(pin_one => first value from lv_string,
                           pin_two => first value from lv_cur
                          )
2. iteration
   procedure process_input(pin_one => second value from lv_string,
                           pin_two => second value from lv_cur
                          )
3. iteration
   procedure process_input(pin_one => third value from lv_string,
                           pin_two => third value from lv_cur
                          )
```

Can you help me find some solution to this problem? Is there maybe a way to write a cursor that would return these value pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key component is creating a routine (could be just a query) that can parse the delimited string into individual numbers and return the result. About the easiest is to create a function that takes a list on delimited numbers and a specified delimiter and returns a collection of numbers. Also create a schema level collection (oracle supplies a couple you could use).

```
-- create a schema level collection of numbers
create or replace 
type list_of_numbers_t 
     is table of number; 
 
-- create a function that parses a string containing a delimited list on numbers
-- and returns the collection defined above
create or replace 
function parse_delimited_list_of_numbers
              (list_of_delimited_numbers_in varchar2 
              ,delimiter_in  varchar2
         )
 return list_of_numbers_t 
 is
     l_parsed_numbers list_of_numbers_t;
     l_regex_pattern  varchar2(16) := '[^<dlm>]+';
begin 
    l_regex_pattern := replace(l_regex_pattern,'<dlm>',delimiter_in); 
    select to_number(trim(regexp_substr(list_of_delimited_numbers_in,l_regex_pattern,1,level)))
      bulk collect 
      into l_parsed_numbers
      from dual connect by 
                regexp_substr(list_of_delimited_numbers_in,l_regex_pattern,1,level) is not null;
    return l_parsed_numbers; 
end parse_delimited_list_of_numbers;
```

See [test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b09b3d87bd283dbe512f262144845936) example here.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the clear explanation and example. I appreciate your help!

Comment: If the answer provided solved your issue please accept it. Do not  leave answered questions open. Accepted answers helps later questioners that may have the same/similar issue.